# Look for NA with a condition, then replace NA with a value depends on the condition

Tags: r

I couldn't figure this out....

I have a data frame looks like this (only the top 10 rows are shown):

```
Value   Type
NA       3      
23       2
54       1
45       1
21       2
55       3
67       3
78       1
10       1
NA       2
```

## Task:

Replace NA with the mean value of its given Type.
Ex:  The first NA is in Type 3, so I'd like to replace it with the average value in Type 3, that is (55+67)/2= 61

## My code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df[i,"Value"])==TRUE & Type==1){
    df[i,"Value"] = mean(with(df, subset(Value, Type==1)))
  }
  else if (is.na(df[i,"Value"])==TRUE & Type==2){
    df[i,"Value"] = mean(with(df, subset(Value, Type==2)))
  }
  else if (is.na(df[i,"Value"])==TRUE & Type==3){
    df[i,"Value"] = mean(with(df, subset(Value, Type==3)))
  }
  else (df[i,"Value"] = df[i,"Value"])
}
```

## Result

NAs are still observed in the Value column and they are not being replaced by the mean value of its class.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should add the `na.rm=TRUE` option to your `mean` function.

Comment: I'd take a look at the `data.table` and `plyr` packages.  This "split-apply-combine` strategy is very common and questions like this have been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: @John:  I tried and found that adding na.rm=TRUE in the mean function replaced all NAs with mean of Type 3 as a result.

Comment: @ohmyan - In your code above you look at the `value` column for types 1 and 2, but the `Fare` column for type 3 - is that causing all the `NAs` to become the mean of type 3? Also, I think maybe you should use `<-` instead of `=` when you replace the `NA`s with the mean.

Comment: @JohnPaul: Fare was a typo.  I corrected the typo and used <- rather than =, but I still got all NAs = the mean of type 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(plyr) 

ddply(dat, .(Type), function(df){
  m <- mean(df$Value, na.rm=TRUE)
  df$Value[is.na(df$Value)] <- m
  df
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two-liner in base R, assuming `X` is your `data.frame`:

```
Means <- tapply(X$Value, X$Type, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
X$Value <- apply(X, 1, function(r) ifelse(is.na(r[1]), Means[r[2]], r[1]))
```

For large datasets, is likely faster than using `ddply`, though the `plyr` and `data.table` packages are more versatile and certainly worth learning.